# Getting the error in changing background color

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

making an app that asks the user for their favorite color, then take them to a new Activity that uses that color as a background color and says something nice about them.
but i dont why its crashing again and agian

heres the code

MainActivity.java

```
private TextView mtextview;
private EditText medittext;
private Button mbutton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mtextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
     medittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name =medittext.getText().toString();
            startStory(name);
        }

        private void startStory(String name) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
```

}

AnotherActivity.java

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

    final RelativeLayout mrelativelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    Intent intent   = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    mrelativelayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(name));

}
```

}

Comment: Check the logcat output and share crash details.

Comment: Please share the exception, you are getting

Comment: What color name you are passing?

Comment: Please share the crash log. Also are you using html color codes for color name field?

Comment: One potential issue can be - you are storing Editable reference "name" inside Intent, but while retrieving you are calling getStringExtra("name") method on intent reference.

Comment: Process: com.example.vishal.newnew, PID: 12550
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vishal.newnew/com.example.vishal.newnew.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are passing color name as "black", "blue", "skyblue" and likewise other color names.

But hope you know about the string parameters value supported by [parseColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)) method.

> Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following
>   names: 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan',
>   'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey',
>   'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuchsia', 'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive',
>   'purple', 'silver', 'teal'.

Answer (score 0):

#### Change 1 :

first of all `AnotherActivity` add below code inside the `OnCreate` method.

`final RelativeLayout mrelativelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main)`;

because it give you `NullPointerException`.

#### Change 2 :

Instead of trying this

```
Editable name = medittext.getText();
```

use this way

```
 String name = medittext.getText().toString();
```

and pass that string to `AnotherActivity` via `Intent`.

Comment: Process: com.example.vishal.newnew, PID: 12550
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vishal.newnew/com.example.vishal.newnew.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: @VishalThadari check your xml you give `button` id with same name you used.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you putExtra in the intent, you convert it to String. 
Currently you are just passing an Editable object and not String object to the intent

Example:

```
intent.putExtra("name",name.toString());
```

or better, change the type of name

```
String name = medittext.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, post your activity_main.xml and activity_another.xml. The problem is that there is not button with android:id="@+id/button" in your activity_main.xml, probably that's in activity_another.xml.